# How to evaluate a three-way interaction with cat. x cat. x time in lme()?

Tags: r, mixed-model, interaction, lme4-nlme

I am ran an experiment with a 2x2 design (reproductive status as Preg/Nonpreg and treatment as stress/nostress) and have mass data for individuals over 9 days (ordinal). After evaluating mass using lme() (see below), I have a significant interaction between reproductive status, treatment, and day. How can I test for differences within this three way interaction? I am primarily interested in differences among groups in the 2x2.

```
wt.lme <- lme(Mass ~ REPRO * TREAT * Day,
                random = ~1|Animal,
                data = rawdata)
```

Output below (w/o correlations):

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
   Data: rawdata 
   AIC      BIC    logLik
   562.5355 598.8117 -271.2678

Random effects:
  Formula: ~1 | Animal
            (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:    1.007436 0.4468402

Fixed effects: Mass ~ Repro * TREAT * Day 
                              Value Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)               19.446663 0.3316500 228 58.63610  0.0000
ReproPREG                 -0.465111 0.4467484  50 -1.04110  0.3028
TREATSTRESS               -0.704780 0.4563695  50 -1.54432  0.1288
Day                       -0.053347 0.0423948 228 -1.25834  0.2096
ReproPREG:TREATSTRESS     -0.033232 0.6010298  50 -0.05529  0.9561
ReproPREG:Day              0.369912 0.0515280 228  7.17885  0.0000
TREATSTRESS:Day            0.047159 0.0543892 228  0.86706  0.3868
ReproPREG:TREATSTRESS:Day -0.292485 0.0647226 228 -4.51905  0.0000

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.73700171 -0.58011247 -0.06799496  0.55300020  3.21875467 

Number of Observations: 286
Number of Groups: 54
```

Comment: This isn't terribly clear. Also, be aware that asking for R code / help w/ code is off topic here. If you are just asking how to conduct tests of simple effects given an interaction, that has nothing to do w/ R necessarily, although you may happen to have conducted your analysis in R. What is mass here? Is it mass as in ~weight? What do you mean that it's ordinal? If it is ordinal, you shouldn't be using `lme`. You don't seem to have a 2x2.

Comment: Mass is indeed weight of the individual. I meant integer - not ordinal - whoops. I just mean that it's not continuous per se. Finally, the design is a 2x2 set-up and then we have weights across time in the experiment. In the end, I'm really just interested in growth rate of individuals within the 2x2 set-up, but we have weights from each day. Thanks for the pointers!